# Create multiple publish tasks in sbt with cross-compilation

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-project `sbt` build and want to create multiple publish commands for publishing different subsets of the projects.

For speed, I normally want to publish only projects `a` and `b` for two Scala versions but occasionally (for example, when a release is cut) I want to publish all of the dependencies, which include projects `c` and `d`.

`build.sbt`:

```scala
val scala212 = "2.12.10"
val scala211 = "2.11.8"
val supportedScalaVersions = Seq(scala212, scala211)
...

lazy val global = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(crossScalaVersions := Nil, ...)
  .aggregate(a, b)

lazy val a = project(...)
lazy val b = project(...)
lazy val c = project(...)
lazy val d = project(...)

...
```

Note that crossScalaVersion is set to `nil` in the aggregating project as recommended [in the sbt reference](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html)

`sbt +publish` will publish just projects `a` and `b` across both scalaversions. If I need to publish all of the dependencies, I publish them individually from the sbt console.

```
sbt> +publish; +c/publish; +d/publish
```

How do I create one command (`+publishAll`) that will publish all of the sub-projects in both Scala versions while keeping default `publish` command only publishing `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `build.sbt`

```
addCommandAlias("publishAll", "publish; c/publish; d/publish")
```

Normal `publish` will always work for your root project and projects it aggregates, so you can move your root project's files to a subproject and change what it aggregates on.

Answer (score 2):

Try `all` in combination with `inAnyProject` like so

```
val publishAll = taskKey[Unit]("Publish all projects")
publishAll := publish.all(ScopeFilter(inAnyProject)).value
```

which will execute `publish` task in all the projects, even those not aggregated by root project.

Comment: This is very clean and seems like it would work except that the project is cross-compiled for 2 different Scala versions, and this only deploys the `ThisBuild / scalaVersion` version. Is there a way to make it work with cross-compilation?

Comment: @MichaelK have you tried running it as `+publishAll`?